# how to pass arguments to a jquery bind-event?

Tags: jquery, arguments, bind

Please can you help me, i don´t find a solution. I have a function with arguments and want to pass this function to a jquery bind-event:

```
function countChars23 (chars) {
    var thi = $(this);
    var len = $(this).val();
    if (len.length >= chars) {
        len = len.substring(0, 22);
        thi.val(len);

    }
}
```

Calling the function don´t work:

```
$('#name').bind('keyup', countChars23(10));
```

This don´t work either:

```
$('#name').bind('keyup', function() {
    countChars23(10);
}
```

This don´t work either:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    countChars23(10);
}
```

Many Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `data` parameter to `.bind`:

```
$('#name').bind('keyup', {chars: 10}, countChars23);
```

and then in your function replace the declared parameter with `event` and put this in the first line:

```
var chars = event.data.chars;
```

**EDIT** the reason your second and third attempts (with the extra function wrapper) don't work is because they don't set `this` properly.  You would have had to have called it like this:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    countChars23.call(this, 10);
}
```

Comment: your first solution worked! my second and third attempts (see above) don´t work, don´t know why! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @drog21 I just figured out why they didn't work - see update.

Comment: @kongaraju perhaps you have a different problem?